# PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer always picking up system properties

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I have a problem with `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`. At the moment, I'm migrating some configuration from xml to java config. I have properties files loaded through a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` configure in an xml document. The problem I have is that now, when I create the java config class using `PropertySourcePlaceholderConfigurer`, there is a property that is being loaded from system and environment properties, not trying to load from the properties file I have. With the `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer` bean you could use

```
<property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
```

That way, the property picked is the one from the system. But I cannot find anything in the `PropertySourcesPlaceHolderConfigurer` similar to this. Actually, in this case it's doing the opposite. Not configuring anything always prefers whatever is in the system. 
The way I use the properties is through an `@Value` annotation and the property that always fails is java.naming.factory.initial, used for a jms connection factory

This is my config with java

```
 @Configuration
 @PropertySources(@PropertySource("classpath:config.properties"))
 public class JndiConfig {

     @Value("${java.naming.factory.initial}")
     private String factoryInitial;

     @Bean
     public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
         return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
     }
}
```

This is the config.properties

```
java.naming.factory.initial=fiorano.jms.runtime.naming.FioranoInitialContextFactory
```

The logs I get are these. Here the property picked to inject fiorano.jms.runtime.naming.FioranoInitialContextFactory

> DEBUG 2015-07-16 15:25:33,269 (org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver) - Searching for key 'java.naming.factory.initial' in [environmentProperties]
>
> DEBUG 2015-07-16 15:25:33,269 (org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver) - Searching for key 'java.naming.factory.initial' in [servletConfigInitParams]
>
> DEBUG 2015-07-16 15:25:33,269 (org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver) - Searching for key 'java.naming.factory.initial' in [servletContextInitParams]
>
> DEBUG 2015-07-16 15:25:33,269 (org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver) - Searching for key 'java.naming.factory.initial' in [jndiProperties]
>
> DEBUG 2015-07-16 15:25:33,269 (org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate) - Looking up JNDI object with name [java:comp/env/java.naming.factory.initial]
>
> DEBUG 2015-07-16 15:25:33,269 (org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorDelegate) - Converted JNDI name [java:comp/env/java.naming.factory.initial] not found - trying original name [java.naming.factory.initial]. javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [java.naming.factory.initial] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [java.naming.factory.initial].
>
> DEBUG 2015-07-16 15:25:33,269 (org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate) - Looking up JNDI object with name [java.naming.factory.initial]
>
> DEBUG 2015-07-16 15:25:33,269 (org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource) - JNDI lookup for name [java.naming.factory.initial] threw NamingException with message: Name [java.naming.factory.initial] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [java.naming.factory.initial].. Returning null.
>
> DEBUG 2015-07-16 15:25:33,269 (org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver) - Searching for key 'java.naming.factory.initial' in [systemProperties]
>
> DEBUG 2015-07-16 15:25:33,269 (org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver) - Found key 'java.naming.factory.initial' in [systemProperties] with type [String] and value 'org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory'
>
> DEBUG 2015-07-16 15:25:33,269 (org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver) - Found key 'java.naming.factory.initial' in [environmentProperties] with type [String] and value 'org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory'
>
> DEBUG 2015-07-16 15:25:33,269 (org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata) - Processing injected element of bean 'jndiConfig': AutowiredFieldElement for private java.lang.String com.iggroup.wt.majormarketmovement.config.JndiConfig.providerUrl

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: The easiest is to rename the property from your `config.properties` and use the following expression in your `@Value` annotation ${name_of_property_in_config_properties:${java.naming.factory.initial}}` what it now does it takes the value of the property file if present else it uses the default. Another workaround could be not using `@Value` and use the `Environment` directly but that would be a bit uglier. A hack would be to specify a `name` attribute in the `@PropertySource` annotation and give it the name `systemProperties` that should work.

Comment: I've tried the renaming already and it obviously works. Using `Environment` I get the same result, it picks the value from the system properties. The hack option doesn't seem to work either. It's not able to find any properties using `name` and `@Value("#{jndiProps['java.naming.factory.initial']}")` and fails. What I don't understand is why `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` allows you to specify this but `PropertySourcePlaceholderConfigurer` doesn't. Specially when it seems using java config that's the only option.

Comment: Itsn't the only option you can still use the `PropertyPlcaeholderConfigurer` just configure it. When using the `Environment` you should pull out the `PropertySources` and first check the one for the property file, then if needed the system properties (but that is manual). When using the name it should merge your properties and system properties (hence the explicit name!) and you shouldn't change the `@Value` expression but leave it as is.

Comment: What I mean is that using `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` with java requires more work than using the other one. To use `@PropertySource`, a `PropertySourcePlaceHolderConfigurer` has to be defined as a bean. Otherwise, as far as I know, `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` would need to be configured as a bean and provided the properties files programatically (without `@PropertySource`) as part of the initialization in order to use `@Value`. That kind of breaks what you can get by just using `@PropertySource` and `PropertySourcePlaceholderConfigurer`.

Comment: About the use of `Environment`, I don't get what you mean by pulling the `PropertySources`. The examples I've found only talks about injecting the instance. The class doesn't have any methods for that so I guess that means that is requires more configuration which kills the simplicity you get by just using `@PropertySource`

Comment: Cast it to a `ConfigurableEnvironment` which has a `getPropertySources()` method. But as stated that is quite ugly. So no there is no extra configuration just a cast.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I think I'm gonna stick to changing the names. It seems like too much of a hassle just to inject some properties.